# Any comprehensive books on global smooth optimization?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation, numerical-optimization, global-optimization

Can you share any information about books that review most of the existing  numerical methods for global minimization of a multivariable objective function? The objective and constraints are assumed to be smooth, I'm **not into integer programming** of any type at the moment.

I'm aware of many local optimization methods, such as steepest descent, Newton and quasi-Newton, conjugate gradients, trust-region methods, etc. But currently I would like to learn some practical ones used specifically for global minimization. Equality and inequality constraints are assumed. Most information I find comes in form of narrow-focused academic papers that are disconnected from each other.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There aren't very many (reasonably-priced) books on the subject in my opinion.
A nice survey article is here:

@article{BOUKOUVALA2016701,

title = "Global optimization advances in Mixed-Integer Nonlinear Programming, MINLP, and Constrained Derivative-Free Optimization, CDFO",

journal = "European Journal of Operational Research",

volume = "252",

number = "3",

pages = "701 - 727",

year = "2016",

issn = "0377-2217",

doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2015.12.018",

url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037722171501142X",

author = "Fani Boukouvala and Ruth Misener and Christodoulos A. Floudas",

}

It explains the main modern methods in teh state of the art solvers like BARON, Antigone, and SCIP.

Shamelessly self-promoting, you might also check out Chapter 5 of our Acta Numerica article.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/mixedinteger-nonlinear-optimization/2D0CE8CDA53363A31ADE8689565517BD

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try "Metaheuristics".  Simulated Annealing, Genetic Algorithm, Tabu search, Ant colony algorithm, swarm intelligence and so on. There will be many books, but I do not know which book is best.

Comment: Do you mean the book "METAHEURISTICS: FROM DESIGN TO IMPLEMENTATION" by El-Ghazali Talbi?

Comment: I didn't mean a specific book by Metaheuristics. Metaheuristics is the name for heuristic optimization methods that can be used in a general optimization problem. I learned some of them by chance but not from a specific book. As I mentioned above, I don't know about books.